# Windows Still Image Architecture basic Python image acquisition

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, winapi, image-processing

We have a very unusual scanner (*Vidar Diagnostic Pro Advantage*) that we are trying to get to work with a very limited driver provided by the manufacturer. 
Unfortunately the provided driver doesn't provide a `WIA` (Windows Image Acquisition) API and operates on (what I understand to be) the lower level `STI` (Still Image Architecture) API.

We only really need basic scanning functionality: ideally an interface with Python would suit us really well for batch processing images.

In order to get started, I am keen to write a basic Python application to acquire an image through the `STI` API. I have installed the `PyWin32` tools but I am not sure where to start when it comes to accessing the underlying C++ API.

I am a bit of a Windows novice unfortunately (my background is Linux). Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Vidar would prefer to sell you an extra piece of software (Clinical Express Dicom Software). But if you're trying to avoid that expense and if you're lucky, this scanner uses the TWAIN interface, and you can use the [Python TWAIN module](https://pypi.org/project/twain/1.0.5/)

Maybe if you're lucky, this scanner will work with Linux. Vidar does not show up on the [list of supported scanners by SANE](http://www.sane-project.org/sane-backends.html) but if you do `lsusb` or `dmesg`, you might get some clues as to how the scanner presents itself and maybe they use some chipset you can talk to with SANE.

Comment: Unfortunately no luck with Linux. I acquired some USB pcap data to try to work out the protocol and asked for help on the xsane mailing list but had no luck. I think the TWAIN driver for this scanner only works with XP and older versions of Windows. The newer driver seems to be Windows `STI` without the `WIA` layer.